# Are ASP.Net WebHooks a good solution and how malleable are they?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webhooks

I have some data about some users in my database. I want to develop a service that send to a client through a URL (preferably a POST HTTP Request) the new data that are inserted in my DB.

To do that, I thought about using ASP.Net WebHooks [(from that tutorial)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/15/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/).

But multiple problems :

- it seems like it's hardly configurable
- can I use my own database tables ?
- the ASP.NET WebHooks solution seems very young (the packages are in prerelease), is it safe to use it now ?

Basically, should I use this solution or, if not, what are the alternatives ? (other library, develop my own solution...).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621664/1370442) here has some interesting info on WebHooks and how to think about them. I'd not come across this so I did some digging, documentation is [here](https://docs.asp.net/projects/webhooks/en/latest/source.html)  . Its currently in RC2 so whether or not it's safe to use is difficult to ascertain. Generally if its "safe" Microsoft release under a "Go Live" type license so as I couldn't see one I'm guessing if you're looking for "done" then no.

If you're happy to fix any breaking changes as it pushes through each RC until it hits 1.0 then yes (at your own risk). There are 18 open issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/issues) right now so I'd also look through those first and see if you can spot anything there that might hinder you if you plan to go ahead.

Have you considered using a normal ASP.NET Web API type project instead?

Comment: I'll look into your link, thanks. About the "normal ASP.NET Web API type project", my project will indeed be a WebApi Project because I'm also planning on develop some "GET" requests for my clients. What do you mean by "instead"?

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.asp.net/web-api I've used it more times than I can count now - should do what you're looking for!